# Polynomial even degree with several identical minima

Tags: functions, polynomials

Is it possible to have a real polynomial P with *even degree* $d=2 k$,  with several minima (say at least in 3 points: $x_1,x_2,x_3$) with all **identical values** $P(x_1)=P(x_2)=P(x_3)$.

Furthermore, is it possible to have a polynomial with the characteristics I say before and with "one side" thinner than the "other" as in the following picture:

[Identical minima one side thinner than the other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpzeR.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't something simple like
$$P(x)=x^2(x-2)^2(x-5)^2$$ fit the bill?

[image]

I hope it's clear how to adjust the separations between the minima, their altitude and their number.

Comment: Yes!! thank you! :)